# CastList<dynamic,String> is not an subtype of type String even after placing cast() flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to parse json response, works fine with string, int type values.
But getting error when having list as values even after placing cast().
Error image is placed at bottom

```
class ChennaiModel{
  final int ra;
  final String ci;
  final bool lo;
  final List<String> ab;

  ChennaiModel({
    this.ra,this.ci,this.lo,this.ab
  });


  factory ChennaiModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>parsedjson){
var streetsFromJson  = parsedjson['streets'];
 List<String> streetsList = streetsFromJson.cast<String>();
    return new ChennaiModel(
         ra:parsedjson['rank'],
         ci:parsedjson['city'],
         lo:parsedjson['love'],
         ab:streetsList

    );
  }
}

Future<ChennaiModel> getchennai() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.https('run.mocky.io','/v3/1496b5ef-873a-48db-9550-75195f2db3b4'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return ChennaiModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try List<String>.from(streetsFromJson)

Comment: Are you sure that exception is coming from that line?  That exception usually would come from trying to do something like `String s = list.cast<String>();`.  What is the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the error isn't from that line. The error I made was i was passing the list inside the Text() widget which expects a string
So later i used an listviewbuilder to traverse and display it

Is there any other ways to traverse and build inside the build() method??

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't in json parsing. The actual error is while building the ui, then using the Text() widget which expects an input as String.If we pass the entire list we get this error.
So we need to Iterate and display in Ui.
Solved by using ListView.builder() to iterate the list.

```
ListView.builder(
               
                itemCount: snapshot.data.ab.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return Text(snapshot.data.ab[index]);
              }),
```